# Sum array in aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm pretty new to MongoDB, and having some problems getting my query as I want it. The documents contain "errors" that have happened a specific time. The result I want from the query is an error count for each month per user. This I have already figured out, but additionally I want the total errorcount per user.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    db.Logger.aggregate([
        { "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$name",
                "month": { "$month": "$errorTime" }
            },
            "totalErrors": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { $group : 
            { _id: { name : "$_id.name"},
                errors: { $addToSet: { totalErrors: { errorsThisMonth: "$totalErrors", currentMonth : "$_id.month" } } },
            }
        }
```

])

The result is:

```
    {
        "_id" : {
            "name" : "abhos"
        },
        "errors" : [ 
            {
                "totalErrors" : {
                    "errorsThisMonth" : 6,
                    "currentMonth" : 2
                }
            }, 
            {
                "totalErrors" : {
                    "errorsThisMonth" : 6,
                    "currentMonth" : 1
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Will it be possible to get what I want by adding to that query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is an additional [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) in your second [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
    db.Logger.aggregate([
        { "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "name": "$name",
                "month": { "$month": "$errorTime" }
            },
            "totalErrors": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id.name",
            "errors": { 
                "$addToSet": { 
                    "errorsThisMonth": "$totalErrors",
                    "currentMonth" : "$_id.month" 
                } 
            },
            "totalErrors": { "$sum": "$totalErrors" }
        }}
])
```

Also you have a few extra document levels you do not need in there, such as extra fields under the `_id` and the "errors" "set" produced in the grouping. This output is just a little different without those additional levels:

```js
    {
        "_id": "abhos"
        "errors" : [ 
            {
                "errorsThisMonth" : 6,
                "currentMonth" : 2
            }, 
            {
                "errorsThisMonth" : 6,
                "currentMonth" : 1
            }
        ],
        "totalErrors": 12
    },
```